# Google shared contact API

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-shared-contacts

I am looking for Googoe Shared conatact API ruby gem.
Is there any good ruby gem for Google Shared Contacts API?

Comment: So I found https://github.com/jparker/gauthic. And working good. Creating, retrieving contacts. But I cann't see it on the web. Where to check it?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/mislav/contacts) is the only one I have found but it has not been maintained for a while. It might need some work.

This [blog post](http://natashatherobot.com/2012/02/03/google-contacts-api-ruby-example/) has a discussion of how to do it on your own if you are interested (and it is more recent).